# selecting the row in gridview using row index

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
  protected void select_click(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     try
    {
        DBLibrary db = new DBLibrary();
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
       * string FeeId = gridv1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;*


         if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {


            string str = "SELECT AnuFeeMaster.FeeId ,AnuFeeMaster.StudentId, Tbl_Student.SName, AnuFeeMaster.Month, AnuFeeMaster.Year, AnuFeeMaster.FeeAmount, " +
                    " AnuFeeMaster.PaidAmount FROM  AnuFeeMaster INNER JOIN Tbl_Student ON AnuFeeMaster.StudentId = Tbl_Student.StudentId where ( AnuFeeMaster.FeeId ='" + FeeId + "')";
            SqlDataReader dr = db.ExecuteReader(str);

            while (dr.Read())
            {

             Session["name"] = dr["sname"].ToString();
             Session["id"] = dr["StudentId"].ToString();
             Session["mth"] = dr["Month"].ToString();
             Session["yr"] = dr["Year"].ToString();
             Session["tot"] = dr["FeeAmount"].ToString();


            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Above is my code what i used to access that i am not getting the value r data from dat Please suggest me, * mark which i used that show where i am getting the error

Comment: _"where i am getting the error"_ what error?? Can you show the aspx?

Comment: What is the exception you get ?

Comment: The data is not retriveing.., from the gridview of the selected row of the cell., null value is getting @ Canavar

Answer (score 0):

You should properly use `RowCommand` event of gridview.

```
void CustomersGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if(e.CommandName=="Select")
{
  int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
  GridViewRow selectedRow = CustomersGridView.Rows[index];
}
}
```

You can catch the button click event like below:

```
protected void MyButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
//Get the button that raised the event
Button btn = (Button)sender;

//Get the row that contains this button
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
}
```

Comment: Are you using boundfield or templatefield?

Comment: i have used template field

Answer (score 0):

create proper grid rowcommand Event
**aspx code**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="Gv" runat="server" AllowPaging="true"   OnRowCommand="Gv_RowCommand" PageSize="10" EmptyDataText="No Records Found !">
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkview" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Demo_Code") %>' CommandName="select" ></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Coulmn1" HeaderText="Coulmn2" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Coulmn2" HeaderText="Coulmn2" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**aspx.cs Code**

```
 protected void Gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
        if (e.CommandName == "select")
        {

        }
}
```